# In a sharded environment, what should happen if my application connect to mongod instead of mongos?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

The data should go to one shard or it will be splitted between the shards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. :-)

There isn't explicit protection against that; in the future that would be a good improvement.  Typically the mongod's in a sharded cluster are running on a different port number than the default so it is difficult to accidentally do that.

A sysadmin may wish to explicitly connect to such a server to inspect it -- that is fine as long as the operations are read only.  You could also do administrative actions there such as a reindex and such.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not doing it, that's why I'm asking :-)